# D3 upon bar chart update selections returns only one datum

Tags: d3.js, selection

I'm trying to build an interactive population pyramid. I want to update the width of the bars.

Something is not working with my selections though. Female and male bars charts are updated to the same width, because they receive the same datum.  I suspect that it has to do with the way I select or join the data. I've tried several combinations, now I'm stuck reading the doc on select and selectAll.

Any comments on what goes wrong here are highly appreciated.

The code ([here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mozyt6td/)):

```
var pyramidCanvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",200)
    .attr("height",100);

var pyramidHeight = 100;
var pyramidWidth = 100;
var pyramidBarsRight, pyramidBarsLeft;

function setupPyramid(){

    var data = [300,20,40,50,10];

    var pyramidHeight = 100;
    var pyramidWidth = 100;

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){return d;})])
        .range([0,pyramidWidth]);

    var barHeight = pyramidHeight/data.length;

    console.log(barHeight);

    pyramidBarsLeft = pyramidCanvas.selectAll("g-female")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",function(d,i){return "translate(0,"+ (i * 10)+ ")" ;});

    pyramidBarsLeft.append("rect")
        .attr("class","female-bar")
        .attr("x",function(d){return pyramidWidth-xScale(d);})
        .attr("y",function(d,i){
            return i*10;
        })
        .attr("width",function(d){console.log(d);return xScale(d);})
        .attr("height",10)
        .style("fill","pink");

    pyramidBarsRight = pyramidCanvas.selectAll("g-male")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",function(d,i){return "translate(0,"+ (i * 10)+ ")" ;});

    pyramidBarsRight.append("rect")
        .attr("class","male-bar")
        .attr("x",pyramidWidth)
        .attr("y",function(d,i){
            return i*10;
        })
        .attr("width",function(d){console.log(d);return xScale(d);})
        .attr("height",10)
        .style("fill","steelblue");

}


function updatePyramid(data){

    var femData = data.slice(0,5);
    var malData = data.slice(5,9);

    console.log(femData);
    console.log(malData);

    console.log(pyramidBarsRight.selectAll("rect"));

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){return d;})])
        .range([0,pyramidWidth]);

    pyramidBarsLeft
        .selectAll(".female-bar")
        .data(femData)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x",function(d){return pyramidWidth-xScale(d);})
        .attr("width",function(d){console.log(d);return xScale(d);})

    pyramidBarsRight
        .selectAll(".male-bar")
        .data(malData)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("width",function(d){console.log(d);return xScale(d);});


}

setupPyramid();
updatePyramid([20,10,50,100,600,30,22,54,91,19,10]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't save the result of an `enter` selection and use it like that. It works fine it you select from the canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/mozyt6td/2/

Comment: Thanks, @LarsKotthoff! That solves the issue. If you put that into an answer, I'll accept it.

tbh, I'm even more puzzled now. Why does it work when I select from the canvas? When I select from the bars, the selection also contains the correct amount of elements.

No need to answer, if it takes too much time. I'm back to reading https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save the result of an `enter` selection and use it like that. It works fine it you select from the canvas, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mozyt6td/2/). The reason is that elements in the `enter` selection merge into the `update` selection once DOM elements have been appended.